# NullPointerException while using jruby

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jruby

I embed jruby script engine into my java program by using `javax.script.ScriptEngineManager`

I made some jruby code that end with `do ~ end` block,
after running all code, NullPointerException occured.
but code ends with any other statement, no exception occurs.

version : 1.7.19

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jruby.embed.variable.Argv.updateARGV(Argv.java:169)
    at org.jruby.embed.variable.Argv.retrieve(Argv.java:158)
    at org.jruby.embed.variable.VariableInterceptor.retrieve(VariableInterceptor.java:154)
    at org.jruby.embed.internal.BiVariableMap.retrieve(BiVariableMap.java:378)
    at org.jruby.embed.internal.EmbedEvalUnitImpl.run(EmbedEvalUnitImpl.java:124)
```

in ARGV.java `updateARGV`

```
if (vars.containsKey((Object)name)) {
    var = vars.getVariable((RubyObject)receiver.getRuntime().getTopSelf(), name);
        var.setRubyObject(argv);
```

vars.getVariable returned null because of isReceiverIdentical return false
in BiVariableMap.java

```
if (var.isReceiverIdentical(receiver)) {
    return var;
}
```

In isReceiverIdentical, this method just compare receiver with BiVariable's receiver usgin '=='.

Is this jruby bug? Or do I have to do something for this?
If you need more information about this problem, plz comment it!

---

I got ScriptEngine(engine) from ScriptEngineManager and set some java instance and method like this

```
engine.put("this", console);
engine.eval("$command = $this.java_method :command, [java.lang.String]");
```

here is my test ruby code. `result` and `tab` is java object
that has some method return String and list.

```
result = $command.call "something to pass"
puts result.getMessage
tabular = result.getData

tabular.each do |tab|
  rows = tab.getRows
  rows.each do |row|
    puts row
  end
  puts tab.getColumnNames
end
```

Comment: I've seen similar NPE issues with JRuby's `BiVariableMap` ... did a [PR](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/pull/2456) to fix it, I'm 95% sure your case is also covered ... if you can build your own *jruby.jar* and verify that would be useful (please comment on the PR with details or reference it from an issue if you're about to open a new one)

Comment: @kares thank you for comment. But... when I built jruby.jar with your changes in embed-internal-cleanup branch, it still throw NPE. Anyway I'll check it more.

Comment: in that case be sure to show some (single snippet) code to reproduce ...

Comment: that is not really an easy-peasy - there's some bits missing I'm not clear on how exactly to trigger this bug ...

Comment: @kares I found solution myself. It's my fault T.T. Anyway thank you for supporting me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had created ruby type object in my java code by creating new `Ruby` object...

This causes checking fail in `updateARGV` because a receiver that register variable in `BiVariableMap` and another receiver that update variable are different.

So, I got a Ruby object from new `ScriptingContainer`(from it we can always get a same Ruby object if local context is singleton) and used it to create new ruby type object in my java code.

Reference: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/RedBridge#Singleton